# ThingsBoards How to change an server attribute using the custom action option in a widget

Tags: json, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

Is it possible to change an server attribute using the custom action option in a widget?
Thanks for help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXR9U.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
let attributeService = widgetContext.$injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('attributeService'));

let attributes = [{
    "key": YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_KEY,
    "value": YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
}];
attributeService.saveEntityAttributes(entityId, 'SERVER_SCOPE', attributes).
    subscribe(
        () => {
            console.log('Saved!');
        },
        error => {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    );
```